# nonmonotone queries

Tags: mysql, sql

**Bars which serve only beer Joe likes**

```
SELECT bar
FROM sells, likes
WHERE likes.drinker = 'Joe' AND sells.beer = likes.beer;
```

**likes(drinker,beer)**
**sells(bar, beer, price)**

I have the simple part of this query down but just don't understand how I get it to print `ONLY` sell, I am getting all bars that sell the beer Joe likes.

*Joe Likes the following beers:*

Hefeweizen

*The Bars that exclusively sell the beers Joe likes are:*

A.P. Stump's

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Get rid of the comma in the `FROM` clause and use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will edit it, but I do not know how to use `JOIN` yet

Comment: . . Then you should not put two tables in the `FROM` clause.  Forget about the comma, and learn the proper way to use SQL.

Comment: SELECT sells.beer
FROM sells
INNER JOIN likes ON (sells.beer = likes.beer)
WHERE likes.drinker = 'Joe';

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have been taught to write it like that

Comment: @num8er that returns `Hefeweiezen` which is not a beer Joe *likes*

Comment: as opposed to rifling off a question per hour why not go to a sql tutorial site and learn the basics. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial site

Comment: @bkennedy nope! Joe likes Hefeweiezen You can check, cuz You join 2 tables by beer param.

Comment: @num8er Oh wow youre right, I just had the wrong name under the likes.

Comment: The plural of sale is sales. Sells is a verb.

Comment: @max what are you getting at here?

Comment: That its not a good table name. Table names are are usually nouns.

Comment: @max I did not create the table names

Comment: @Drew do you have any preferred SQL tutorials or sites that you think help the most? My biggest problem right now is just transitioning from an english statement to a query, I have the simple ones down but others are hard

Comment: I often just say [this](http://tutorialspoint.com/mysql/) one but I have never spent time on it. Feel free to ask for help in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) chat but keep it within reason. I am always happy to help. (for a while :p) . You will get up to speed quickly once you do it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long talk in comments I understood that @bkennedy wants to get bar name that sells only the beer that `Joe` likes to drink.

It means that some `X` bar sell only `Z` beer.

So the query will be like:

```
SELECT 
  bar
FROM 
  sells
WHERE
  bar IN (
    SELECT
      sells.bar
    FROM
      sells
    INNER JOIN likes ON (sells.beer = likes.beer)
    WHERE
      likes.drinker = 'Joe'
) 
GROUP BY 
  bar 
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: I am looking for the bar that sells beers joe likes so i changed the original `SELECT sells.beer` to `SELECT sells.bar` despite that its still printing another bar that sells an additional beer that joe DOES NOT like.

Comment: @bkennedy You want to get bar that Joe likes the concrette beer?

Comment: what are you asking I am not understanding

Comment: it does not only return the bar that explicitly sells Hefeweizen, it also prints another bar that sells another beer besides that

Comment: @bkennedy OMG! You don't understand! If You know that Joe likes what beer and where he likes to drink so WhatTaFunc You ask DB to tell the bar name? (:   Also anothe bar is selling the Hefeweizen, so that's why it's showing up! check tables carefully!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124171/discussion-between-bkennedy-and-num8er).